# jQuery custom plugin, keep set variables relevant to selected item?

Tags: jquery, plugins

This is my first time developing a jQuery plugin. Basically I'm just writing this to merge functions together and make using those functions a lot easier, something like writing a class with methods.

What I'm having trouble with, is that after I use my jQuery command on an element - all information from within that function is lost and I cannot use it for later use. I'd like to use the plugin as sort of a class, with functions as methods. I want to save Raphael created objects inside of it, and manipulate them later on if needed. Here is my example:

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.myPlugin = function(step) {
        if(step == 'step1') {
            var test = 'Function OK!';
            console.log(test);
        }
        if(step == 'step2') {
            console.log(test);
        }
    }
})(jQuery);

$('#elem').myPlugin('step1');
$('#elem').myPlugin('step2');
```

Of course the first console log prints out the variable, however the second returns undefined.

Is there a way to have jQuery act as a self reliant class, with closed variables? As I mentioned, I want to create Raphael objects and later manipulate them. So I need to assign the Raphael object to a variable (`var graph = Raphael('#elem', options);`), so later on I'd need to have access to it by calling a function to it, something like `graph.somefunction(doThis);`

How can I do this? Am I doing something wrong? Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Store the data on each element.

```
$.fn.myPlugin = function(step){

    return this.each(function(){
        var $elem = $(this);
        if(step == 'step1') {
            $elem.data('test','Function OK!');
            console.log('step1',this.id,$elem.data('test'));
        }
        if(step == 'step2') {
            console.log('step2',this.id,$elem.data('test'));
        }
    });

};

$('#elem').myPlugin('step1').myPlugin('step2');
```

It also now supports more than one element at a time with different step progress.

```
$('#elem1').myPlugin('step1');
$('#elem2').myPlugin('step1').myPlugin('step2');
$('#elem1').myPlugin('step2');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/FaaBV/